# Get Heartbeat from Apple Watch (HKHeartbeatSeriesBuilder)

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I am interested in measuring the time interval for each heartbeat during a specific time period.

How can you start a new session to collect the heartbeats from Apple watch? Can you achieve that with HKHeartbeatSeriesBuilder? How?